# Show that $n(1-\sqrt[n]{n})\to-\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} n(1 -\sqrt[n]{n}) = -\infty$, using the following bounds if necessary:

(a) $n(n+1)^{1/n} < n+s_n$ for $n>1$

(b) $(n-1)(n)^{\frac{-1}{n+1}} < n - s_n$ for $n>2$

EDIT: Here $s_n$ is the harmonic sum.

My ideas were: If the sequence is bounded below by constant multiple of $s_n$, then it is divergent. 
I used (b) which gives,

$s_n < n^{\frac{-1}{n-1}}(n^{\frac{n}{n-1}} - n + 1 )$

and as we limit $n \rightarrow \infty$, the term $n^{\frac{-1}{n+1}}$ limits to $1$. We also have

$ \frac{n^{\frac{n}{n-1}} - n + 1}{n(\sqrt[n]{n} -1 )} = \frac{n^{\frac{1}{n-1}} - 1 + \frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt[n]{n} -1} \rightarrow \frac{n^{\frac{1}{n-1}} - 1}{n^\frac{1}{n} -1}$

It suffices to show the latter limits to a constant. Which I somehow could not find.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your "bounds" make no sense because "$s_n$" is not defined.

Comment: @Peter "The limit is $-\infty$ because $n^{1/n}>1$ for $n\ge 2$." This argument is false, please do not send the OP into deadends or into wrong solutions, even in comments.

Comment: OP: 9 months on the site, 15 questions, please show some work.

Comment: @Did, you mean I should post some of my workings?

Comment: Exactly. Didn't you read some howtoask page before starting to dump your questions on the site?

Comment: @Did I wanted to show a typo and formulated this unlucky.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

A simpler solution:

$$n^{\tfrac1n}=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\ln n}n}=1+\frac{\ln n}n+o\biggl(\frac{\ln n}n\biggr), \quad\text{hence}\quad1-n^{\tfrac1n}\sim_\infty -\frac{\ln n}n.$$